# Load angularjs views on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Does anyone knows how to load angularjs views on page load? This will improve speed and minimize network traffic. For example this:

```
<div ng-switch-when="home">
    <div ng-include="'views/home.html'"></div>
</div>
```

"**home.html**" to be included from cache and without request to server every time the view is changed.
Thanks.

Comment: I think it's safer and angular way to set this with route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include templates on a page with

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="views/home.html">
    <yourtemplatehere/>
</scipt>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script

Comment: Can I set src of the template in script tag? There is no description in the documentation.

Comment: @Ivica I don't know. You could always try it. An alternative is to run through an array of template-urls to pre-fetch them and store them in the [template cache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache)